# Android bluetooth wake up device

Tags: android, bluetooth

I bought myself a smartwatch that has Android KitKat running.
I have connected it to my HTC m9 smartphone using Bluetooth.
I have created an application that is running on both smartwatch(client mode) and smartphone(server mode).
The applications are talking each other over a Bluetooth Socket connection.

When I get a phone call on my phone, I am sending a Bluetooth notification over the Bluetooth socket to the watch and make it vibrate.

All is good as long as the watch's CPU is up and running.
When the watch goes to sleep, and I get a phone call on the smartphone, the notification is not processed by the watch because watch's CPU is sleeping.

Using a partial lock on the watch does the thing but it consumes the battery to fast.
I don't need a partial lock on the phone, because when the phone receives a call, the phone is "magically" awaken, so my application's service is able to send the notification.

I also can't use AlarmManager on the watch, because I need the watch to wake up when I get a bluetooth socket notification, not on regular intervals.

A WakefullRecevier is also not solving the problem because my watch needs to wake up first so that the WakefullReceiver puts the power lock (or have I got this wrong ?!) and runs its code.

So the question is:  How does the phone wake up on incoming call? Or on SMS received? It is a hardware thing..an interrupt? 
Is there any way of waking up the watch when a bluetooth message is received?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

For the past few days I've been playing around with the watch making different tests.
I am not answering the original question but since nobody else answered the question I will just write down my own conclusions which are good enough for my application and maybe help others with similar problems.

**1. When the paired watch is in Bluetooth range of the phone, a power lock is not needed on the watch**. 
Any messages sent by the phone are received by the watch. 
If the watch stays idle for some time, the 1st Bluetooth message sent by the phone is received with about 1 second delay. Probably Android watch goes into some kind of low power mode but is able run my code when Bluetooth message is received. Of course Bluetooth messages are received almost immediately by the watch while the watch is not idle.

**2. Best way to find out if a Bluetooth socket is still connected, is to write into it.**
Socket read is a blocking call but it does not throw `IOException` when watch goes out of Bluetooth range. I wasn't able to find a read timeout property I can change.
So I am just writing a byte into the socket every 60 seconds to detect if socket is not connected anymore. Battery impact is minimum while socket down detection timing is acceptable.

**3. When the paired watch is NOT in Bluetooth range of the phone anymore, Bluetooth socket re-connect strategy is required.**
Using a partial lock in this case does not seem like a good approach since it keeps the CPU awake. Also trying to re-connect to often to the phone kills the battery.

The re-connect strategy is based on application needs. 
I ended up using `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` and `AlarmManager` to make a socket connect attempt with a given period.

**4. Every now and then, when the watch goes out of Bluetooth range, then comes back into range, then again and again the Bluetooth socket seems to go in some kind of 'zombie' state**. Sometimes the `socket.connect` call just blocks without succeeding or throwing error, some other times the `socket.connect`call does not throw error given the impression that connection has been established, but a subsequent write always throws `IOException`.
Whenever I encounter these kinds of situations I just stop/start Bluetooth adapter which seems to solve the problem.

**5. Pay attention to stop/start the Bluetooth adapter.** During Bluetooth restart attempt Android can put the CPU to sleep. I wasn't expecting this behavior but it really happens. So if you want to do this as fast as possible without any delay, make sure the application acquires a `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` during the re-start attempt. Of course don't forget to release the lock as soon as possible.